# Translate several files in a ZIP file

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-navisworks

Using the Forge model derivatie API, is it possible to translate several models in a zip file even if the models are not internally linked?

I have some very large Navisworks models and if I link them, the viewer is painfully slow. What I would like to do is to split the model into mutiple smaller models, put them in a zip file and translate them. Then I would like to only display the sub models I choose to. I have tried to do this, but I can only find the model set as root model.

Answer (score 0):

You can translate individual split up models, but they have to be in separate uploads. You can aggregate more than one models in one Viewer after you translated them for better performance on large models. There's a [blog post](https://forge.autodesk.com/cloud_and_mobile/2016/02/model-aggregation-with-view-data-api-exposed.html) on how to do that.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I have looked at aggregating several models in one Viewer and it works quite well. But it do require additional work, like building a new model structure panel. It would be great if this was handled in the translation. Is this something that is beeing looked at?

Comment: AFAIK no. You can also hide parts of the model, but it still requires models to be loaded into the scene.

Comment: This would be somehow against the use of the translation service, so it is very unlikely it would be looked at: the use of the service is charged per translation no matter the size or complexity of the model, however you can only convert a single upload to one model, as Shiya mentioned you would need to either perform multiple uploads or handle a big model. Sorry for the bad news.